# How to set auto increment a primary key with a huge data in table in postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, postgresql-9.4

We are using rails4 with postgresql .
We have restore database from a dump in postgresql .

We have orders table which is shown below.

## \d orders;

```
Table "public.orders"
               Column               |            Type             |                      Modifiers                      
------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id                                 | integer                     | not null default nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass)
 store_id                           | integer                     | 
 customer_id                        | integer                     | 
 number                             | character varying(255)      | 
 order_status_id                    | integer                     | 
 product_total                      | double precision            | 
 discount_total                     | double precision            | 
 tax_total                          | double precision            | 
 shipping_total                     | double precision            | 
 total_cost                         | double precision            | 
 created_at                         | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at                         | timestamp without time zone |
```

We found the sequence is present . But when creating the order the ids are not autoincremented .

What should be the cause?

------------------------COMMANDS -------------------

```
> show search_path;
   search_path   
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)



> \ds;
             List of relations
 Schema |                 Name                 |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+--------------------------------------+----------+----------
public | orders_id_seq                        | sequence | postgres
```

Comment: Have you tested the sequence with a SELECT nextval('orders_iq_seq'); ? Does that work and increment? It could be a permissions issue.

Comment: I run SELECT nextval('orders_iq_seq');  and got ERROR:  relation "orders_iq_seq" does not exist

Comment: What's the result of: show search_path; and \ds (assuming you're using psql).

Comment: Sorry last comment :(
SELECT nextval('orders_id_seq'); produces  356931

This is next id

Comment: show search_path; -> "$user", public ....  \ds -> public | orders_id_seq                        | sequence | postgres

Comment: That looks good. Have you tried calling the same command as the user that is creating the orders?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112176/discussion-between-debadatt-and-d1ll1nger).

Comment: @d1ll1nger please check the chat